# MPOS doesn't accept credit card payment D365

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, point-of-sale, dynamics-365-operations

This is on a test environment.

Using D365 Retail.

Modern Point of sales (MPOS)

The terminal device is a Verifone P400Plus from  Adyen.

I'm getting this error on the MPOS when paying with a credit card:

> "The card type is not an accepted form of payment. Use a different
>   payment card, and then try again"

[image]

The card I'm using is a test card with the following details:

> Mastercard/Maestro
>
> EXP: 31/12/2025
>
> Version: 012
>
> Cardnumber: 541333 **** 9999
>
> Type: CREDIT

In D365\Retail\Channel setup\POS setup\Hardware profiles, I've added Master and Maestro card to the hardware profile:

[image]

In D365\Retail\Channel setup\Payment methods\Card numbers, I've added the card number on both MasterCard and Maestro
[image]

In D365\Retail\Channel setup\Payment methods\Card types, the cards are also present
[image]

Job 1070 and 1090 has been applied.

I might be missing something that I don't know about, but I've no clue what to look for. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I did a full push, but the same error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what was causing the MPOS to trigger the error. It was due to the card type. The mastercard was configured to have the "Card types" value set to "International debit card".
[image]
In the js file "Commerce.Core.js" line 49377, the code calls the method "Commerce.PaymentHelper.isCreditCard(...) where it checks for the credit card.

When my mastercard was configured to "International debit card" the if statement inside of the method wasn't true so my card would always be rejected. Changing the Card types value for mastercard to "International credit card" or "Corporate card" solved my problem.
[image]